# Support Vector Machines - Predicting popularity of articles - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Raw data:

> Article content and title. 10000 articles

Features: (I extracted them from the data)

> Number of words of the title
>
> Number of words of the article
>
> Number of Facebook Likes
>
> Publication Period: Weekend or not

Firstly let me say that I'm very new to ML.

I'm trying to use the data I have to build a model with SVM. This model will predict if an article is likely to be popular or not. I assumed an article is popular if its number of FB likes is bigger than 2000.

I created a 5D map (4 dimension for the 4 features and 1 for the binary popularity information) with the training data. Each article and its features will have a dot in 5D space.

I'm trying to use this 5D map with SVM so that it will create an optimal margin.

Then I'll use this margin to predict popularity with test data.

When it comes to implementation, I'm very much stuck.

Am I doing something wrong? How should I use SVM with this problem?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What language/software and kernel are you using to implement the SVM?

Comment: @ode2k hoping to use linear polynomial and gaussian as kernel. language is matlab at the moment

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think your features are good enough to predict if something is popular? Thing about all the information you've thrown away (the content of the actual document), the information your missing (who is the source of the publication, what does their network look like) questions that aren't obvious from your data (popular with whom? Different groups of people may like / dislike different things).

You need to

1. Learn more about Machine Learning in general.
2. Learn about feature engineering, look for some previous work people have done with text based data (sentiment analysis, topic modeling, spam filtering).
3. Learn to build and test hypothesis with your data. While in this case, its obvious you are probably making a *lot* of errors -- but thats mostly because this is novice work. These questions in general will always be problem and data dependent, so its often not helpful to provide generic information and ask for advice. Once you learn some more ML, you need to think about what your models mean - and what their performance means. From that you can build a hypothesis about your performance, and try and test it. Based on the results, you change something about your model or data and repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I don't think the features are that good. Your overall suggestion is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to use the features with several ML methods. Then observe the accuracy for each one. Then, try to explain why I get the results I get in my mind. I'm not after a good prediction at this point.  I just want to "thoroughly" work on this problem in a "introduction" level. I read many project papers but they all skip important details assuming  I know them. What should I do to quickly get my hands dirty?

Comment: "I read many project papers but they all skip important details assuming I know them" then you should go find those details. Quick and dirty is the wrong way (IMHO) to go about learning.